# after update concrete5 file template auto nav block not load

Tags: concrete5

Anyone know Why: after update concrete5 to new version , file `concrete/block/autonav/view.php` template auto nav block not load.

Example i added class in view.php:

```
if ($ni->hasSubmenu) {
    //class for items that have dropdown sub-menus
    $classes[] = 'has-sub';
}
```

But not see any class that before update everything run perfect.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a template you should put it in root/blocks/autonav/template_name/view.php

If you modified directly concrete/blocks/autonav/view.php then when you update your modification don't apply anymore because that file is not taken into account anymore. The one used after updating is the same file but in the update folder.

I suggest then you copy the view.php file you modified originally and create a proper template by putting it where I said root/blocks/autonav/template_name/view.php then apply the template to the autonav